# Creating breadcrumbs based on content type relationships

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

Currently I have 3 different content types: Program, Chapter, Item. A program contains multiple chapters and a chapter contains multiple items. These are related to one another using node reference field types.

On the item page I would like to have a breadcrumb listing: Program --> Chapter that is related to that specific item node.

I've looked into [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) and [Page Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs), but can't seem to figure out how to pull in the chapter and program that it is related to.

Comment: In which direction does the entityreference field go? Child pointing to parent, or parent pointing to child?

Comment: And, could you rename the question to breadcrumbs based on entity reference field? (note: there is no "node reference" in D7, there is only "entity reference"). There is also a "relation" module, but this is not what you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being I was able to figure it out by adding node reference fields to each of the content types. Then referencing my items to the chapters. I then found the [Corresponding Entity Reference Module](https://drupal.org/project/cer) and used that to link them up. Using [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) I could use the reference tokens to create my breadcrumb.

Only downside is that I had to go into each item node. Took some time!

Answer (score 0):

Try achieving it by [Hansel Breadcrumb](https://drupal.org/project/hansel) module. I don't have experience with situation of your kind but it works well for rule based breadcrumb. Module page describe :

> - Rules can be organized in a hierarchical structure.
> - Possible to leave breadcrumbs as is for specific sections.
> - Other modules can add switch types and breadcrumb actions by implementing the hansel_switch_types and hansel_action_types hooks.
> - An import / export module is included.
> - Export configuration in DOT format for visualisation (new).
> - Test functionality is available where you can see which steps are    executed to get the actual breadcrumbs for a given path.
> - Integration with forum module (new).
> - Integration with token module.
> - Integration with domain module.
> - Integration with og module (new).
> - Integration with realname module.
> - Settings for trimming of titles and whole breadcrumb items.

Comment: Yeah I tried that module. Unfortunately there is no documentation, not much support, and it is very complicated so I was not able to figure out how to use it. If it's even possible. :(